# Standardized residuals

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, variance, standard-error

I am having a hard time understanding the concept of standardizing residuals and how the variance of a residual is decomposed. In a linear model, we defined residuals as:

$e = y - \hat{y} = (I-H)y$ where H is the hat matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

and we defined standardized residuals as:

$r_i = \frac{e_i}{s\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$,  $i = 1,...,n$

where $s^2$ is the usual estimate of $\sigma^2$, $var(e_i) = \sigma^2h_{ii}$, and $h_{ii}$ is the diagonal entry of H at the $i^{th}$ row and $i^{th}$ column

However, I am not sure why $r_i$ and $e_i$ are functions of $h_{ii}$ rather than the whole row $h_i$. Basically I am confused about what $h_{ii}$ stands for as opposed to row $h_{i}$.

Comment: I assume that $h_{ii}$ is the element in row $i$ and column $i$. That is the $i^{th}$ diagonal element of the hat matrix.

Comment: @BradS. yes sorry. I will add that

Comment: $r_i$ and $e_i$ are scalars as is $h_{ii}$ but $h_i$ is a vector. The equation you have posted for the standardized residuals is a scalar equation. How would it even make sense for $e_i$, a scalar,  to depend upon a whole row of the hat matrix?

Comment: @BradS. To me $e_i$ is the scalar residual value for the $i^{th}$ entry of the y vector. However, $\hat{y}$ is determined using the $i^{th}$ row of the $X$ matrix. That is why I am thinking $var(e_i)$ should depend on the $i^{th}$ row of the hat matrix rather than one cell. I am not saying it should equal to the row but it would make more sense to me if it was like an average of the row. Thank you! I can clarify it further if you'd like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the variance of the residuals vector $e$,
$$
Var(e) = Var( (I-H)y ) = (I-H)^TVar(y) (I-H) = \sigma^2(I-H).
$$
The main diagonal of $\sigma^2(I -H)$ are the variance terms of $e$. Particularly, the variance of $e_i$ is the $i$th diagonal element of $\sigma^2(I-H)$, that is $\sigma^2(1 - h_{ii})$. Since you don't know $\sigma^2$ and estimate it with $s^2$, thus the estimated variance of $e_i$ is $s^2(1-h_{ii})$.

Comment: thanks so much! This explains it really well